# Android Subscription Cancellation

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription, cancellation

I have a in app purchase that allows user to subscribe to annual service.

In case of cancellations & refund via Merchant Center it seems that the user will still have access to the product for this billing cycle (whole year).

How do I fully revoke & cancel a subscription in the current billing cycle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case of cancellation there is no refund to the user. When a user cancels subscription it means that when the current subscription expires there will be no auto-renew (purchase).

Quote from docs:

> When the user cancels a subscription, Google Play does not offer a refund for the current billing cycle. Instead, it allows the user to have access to the canceled subscription until the end of the current billing cycle, at which time it terminates the subscription. For example, if a user purchases a monthly subscription and cancels it on the 15th day of the cycle, Google Play will consider the subscription valid until the end of the 30th day (or other day, depending on the month).

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#cancellation